# Opening link to facebook page from facebook crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I am sharing a feed on wall. The link is a link to some facebook page.

When the link is pressed from chrome, the page opens properly, [image: Opens from chrome]

but when I try to open it in iPhone, the page crashes.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
...
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"name",@"name",
    @"description", @"description",
    [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://www.facebook.com/Kyoto.sushi"], @"link", 
    @"caption", @"caption",
    [NSString stringWithFormat:pictureUrl], @"picture",
    @"message",@"message",
    nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
...
```

I pressed copy the URL, and got this one:
`fb://faceweb/f?href=%2FKyoto.sushi%3Fid%3D100616296685390%26_rdr` guess Facebook recognizes that it is a Facebook link and converts it to something. And this something doesn't really work.

Comment: Luda I tried posting your code from my app, and the link worked great both in the browser and in the native Facebook app..

Comment: Eyal, are you sure that after posting the feed, you have managed to find your post in the facebook application, tap on the link and managed to open the sushi page?

Comment: You can see for yourself, search for the user roykarn@gmail.com, and check out the wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL has http:// and https://

```
http://https://www.facebook.com/Kyoto.sushi
```

that should be

```
https://www.facebook.com/Kyoto.sushi
```